# How to prove that the tangent map $T\phi$ into the pullback bundle is smooth?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Assume $\phi: M\rightarrow N$ is smooth. Let $\phi^*(TN)$ be the pullback bundle of $TN$ by $\phi$. Define $T\phi:TM\rightarrow \phi^*(TN)$ as follows:  $T\phi(m,v)=(m,d\phi_m(v)) $.

We also have the corresponding bundle morphism (covering $\phi$), $\bar \phi : \phi^*(TN)\rightarrow TN$, which I think is smooth by the construction of the smooth structure on the pullbak bundle $\phi^*(TN)$.

So, we have a composition of maps which satisfies: 
$\bar \phi (T\phi)=d\phi$ where $d\phi:TM\rightarrow TN$ is the usual differential map between the corresponding tangent bundles induced by $\phi$.

I know that $d\phi,\bar \phi$ are smooth. How can I show $T\phi$ is smooth?

I would also be happy to find some reference on this subject (I am reading Lee's Intro' to smooth manifolds, and he doesn't treat pullbacks of vector bundles).

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    TM @>T\phi>> \phi^*(TN)\ @> \bar \phi>> TN
   \end{CD}

Answer (score 0):

For each smooth vector bundle $E\to N$ [$\phi^*(E)$ is an embedded submanifold of $M\times E$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334071/the-pullback-bundle-is-an-embedded-submanifold-of-its-parent-space). Hence as

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    TM @>T\phi>> \phi^*(TN)\ @> inc>> M\times TN
   \end{CD}

is smooth so is $T\phi$.